# Sitecore Services Client vs Sitecore Web Service vs Sitecore Item web API

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm a Sitecore beginner, working on Sitecore 8 with ASP.NET.
There is a page where an Ajax call has to be made to get data.

Created a test web service in the project which responds to the ajax call with success. This service will be a wrapper.

I understand, I have to consume one of the 3 options (in the title) inside the test service, to get the Sitecore items and do stuff.

But all 3 appear similar to me & not sure which one to go with, to achieve my task

Also,
1. Is there an advantage of one over the other.
2. ..and when to use which one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sitecore Services Client is the framework or namespace that both Item Service and Entity Service sit within. Item Web API is the legacy framework.

Use Item service if you want to do basic stuff with the sitecore Items as this is a prebuilt api. Entity Service allows you to create your own API using the Sitecore.Services.Client framework and give you much more power and control.

https://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/01/06/entityservice-sitecore-service-client/

Use can also use Sitecore.Services.Client to do the routing and you write the controller. see https://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/06/25/sitecore-service-client-servicesapicontroller/

Comment: Entity Service? Is it different from those 3?

Comment: Sitecore Services Client that you mention is a framework and namespace rather than a web service. It contains both Item Service and Entity Service these are both web services. Not sure what you mean by "Sitecore web service". Item Web API is the old legacy web service and wouldn't recommend using that now. You can just write your own MVC controller than returns JSON too

Comment: I am using ASP.NET and not MVC. By Sitecore Web Service, I was referring to https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_web_service_sc65_a4.pdf

Comment: Don't use that for writing API's for a website. That API shouldn't be available on a live website only a content authoring server. Those documents are for Sitecoer 6.5, your on Sitecore 8, refer here doc.sitecore.net. You can still add in an Web API controller you write your self in a WebForms project, or use Entity Service.

Comment: My task is to create a web service, which in turn will consume a sitecore service to get items and return to ascx. From what you say, `Sitecore.Services.Client` is the only option. am i right ?

Comment: Two choices: either Entity Service with(Sitecore.Services.Client) or create your own Web API controller (you can mix web api with Web Forms). like this https://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/04/12/add-custom-web-api-controller-to-sitecore-solution/